# Identificar tipo de dato en un rango

Tags: google-hoja-de-cálculo

a ver si me explico, yo jalo una lista de datos desde un webhook a mi archivo de google sheets, pero esta lista queda guardada en UNA SOLA CELDA, de la siguiente forma:

***105605,2020/05/04,15:00,Nombre de la empresa,Avenida Acueducto 3099,Colonia Insurgentes,Morelia,Michoacán,58250,Mexico,pickup***

¿Cómo puedo yo hacer para identificar la fecha y la hora de ese conjunto de datos? Nota: no siempre llegan en el mismo orden, si fuera así, sé que puedo utilizar una combinación de fórmulas INDICE y SPLIT, pero como dije, no siempre llegan en el mismo orden los datos, por ejemplo, a veces la fecha queda en la segunda o tercera posición.

¿Habrá alguna forma de identificar cuál dato es fecha, hora, número o texto; y extraerlo?

Gracias.

Comment: Con que lenguaje de programacion estas trabajando?

Comment: ninguno, formulas de google sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Si la lista de datos se agrega a una celda las Hojas de Cálculo de Google consideran el contenido de la celdas como un valor de tipo texto.

Como la lista de datos cuenta con un separador, puedes usar SPLIT para convertir la lista en una matriz, luego para determinar el tipo de dato de cada celda de la matriz puedes usar funciones como

- [ESTEXTO (ISTEXT)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093297?hl=es)
- [ESNUMERO (ISNUMBER)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093296?hl=es)

entre otras similares.

Es importante hacer notar que las hojas de cálculo de Google usan números seriales para manejar las fechas-horas (fecha, hoja, duración)

Si quieres hacerlo todo en una única fórmula, esta será compleja. Quizás deberás primero  intentar hacerlo con fórmulas simples y usando rangos auxiliares hasta que entiendas bien como lograr lo que estás buscando.